# E2134 Error in Turbopower LockBox code when building with runtime type information

Tags: delphi, rtti, delphi-10.4-sydney, lockbox-3

I have to build my program with runtime type information, so compiler option *Emit runtime type information* is checked.
But with this set the LockBox3 unit `uTPLb_codecIntf.pas` gives error *E2134 Type  has no type info* on the line containing *Implementation* (see bottom of source).

The `LockBox3\run\` (source) folders are in my library path (as specified by the installation).
LockBox DCU's are in `d:\LockBox3\packages\Sydney\Delphi\Win32\Release\` and date from the time of installation.

How can I get rid of the error message yet have RTTI available?

**Edit** FWIW, these are the contents of `uTPLb_codecIntf.pas`:

```
interface
uses SysUtils, Classes, uTPLb_StreamCipher, uTPLb_BlockCipher,
     uTPLb_CryptographicLibrary;

type
TCodecMode = (cmUnitialized, cmIdle, cmEncrypting, cmDecrypting);

TOnEncDecProgress = function ( Sender: TObject; CountBytesProcessed: int64): boolean of object;

TGenerateAsymetricKeyPairProgress = procedure (
  Sender: TObject; CountPrimalityTests: integer;
  var doAbort: boolean) of object;


ICodec = interface
  ['{48B3116A-5681-4E79-9013-8EC89BAC5B35}']
    procedure SetStreamCipher( const Value: IStreamCipher);
    procedure SetBlockCipher ( const Value: IBlockCipher);
    procedure SetChainMode   ( const Value: IBlockChainingModel);
    function  GetMode: TCodecMode;
    function  GetStreamCipher: IStreamCipher;
    function  GetBlockCipher : IBlockCipher;
    function  GetChainMode   : IBlockChainingModel;
    function  GetOnProgress  : TOnEncDecProgress;
    procedure SetOnProgress( Value: TOnEncDecProgress);
    function  GetAsymetricKeySizeInBits: cardinal;
    procedure SetAsymetricKeySizeInBits( value: cardinal);
    function  GetAsymGenProgressEvent: TGenerateAsymetricKeyPairProgress;
    procedure SetAsymGenProgressEvent( Value: TGenerateAsymetricKeyPairProgress);
    function  GetKey: TSymetricKey;

    function  GetCipherDisplayName( Lib: TCryptographicLibrary): string;

    procedure Init(const Key: string; AEncoding: TEncoding);
    procedure SaveKeyToStream( Store: TStream);
    procedure InitFromStream( Store: TStream);
    procedure InitFromKey( Key: TSymetricKey);   // Transfers ownership.
    procedure Reset;
    procedure Burn( doIncludeBurnKey: boolean);

    // Asymetric support
    function  isAsymetric: boolean;
    procedure InitFromGeneratedAsymetricKeyPair;

    procedure Sign(
      Document, Signature: TStream;
      ProgressSender: TObject;
      ProgressEvent: TOnEncDecProgress;
      SigningKeys_PrivatePart: TObject;  // Must be uTPLb_Asymetric.TAsymtricKeyPart
      var wasAborted: boolean);

    function VerifySignature(
      Document, Signature: TStream;
      ProgressSender: TObject;
      ProgressEvent: TOnEncDecProgress;
      SigningKeys_PublicPart: TObject; // Must be uTPLb_Asymetric.TAsymtricKeyPart
      var wasAborted: boolean): boolean;


    procedure Begin_EncryptMemory( CipherText{out}: TStream);
    procedure EncryptMemory(const Plaintext: TBytes; PlaintextLen: Integer);
    procedure End_EncryptMemory;

    procedure Begin_DecryptMemory( PlainText{out}: TStream);
    procedure DecryptMemory( const CipherText{in}; CiphertextLen: integer);
    procedure End_DecryptMemory;

    procedure EncryptStream( Plaintext, CipherText: TStream);
    procedure DecryptStream( Plaintext, CipherText: TStream);

    procedure EncryptFile( const Plaintext_FileName, CipherText_FileName: string);
    procedure DecryptFile( const Plaintext_FileName, CipherText_FileName: string);

    procedure EncryptString(const Plaintext: string; var CipherText_Base64: string; AEncoding: TEncoding);
    procedure DecryptString(var Plaintext: string; const CipherText_Base64: string; AEncoding: TEncoding);

    procedure EncryptAnsiString(const Plaintext: string; var CipherText_Base64: string);
    procedure DecryptAnsiString(var Plaintext: string; const CipherText_Base64: string);

    function  GetAborted: boolean;
    procedure SetAborted( Value: boolean);
    function  GetAdvancedOptions2 : TSymetricEncryptionOptionSet;
    procedure SetAdvancedOptions2( Value: TSymetricEncryptionOptionSet);
    function  GetOnSetIV: TSetMemStreamProc;
    procedure SetOnSetIV( Value: TSetMemStreamProc);

    property  Mode: TCodecMode                   read GetMode;
    property  Key: TSymetricKey                  read GetKey;
    property  StreamCipher: IStreamCipher        read GetStreamCipher write SetStreamCipher;
    property  BlockCipher : IBlockCipher         read GetBlockCipher  write SetBlockCipher;
    property  ChainMode   : IBlockChainingModel  read GetChainMode    write SetChainMode;
    property  OnProgress  : TOnEncDecProgress    read GetonProgress   write SetOnProgress;
    property  AsymetricKeySizeInBits: cardinal   read GetAsymetricKeySizeInBits
                                                 write SetAsymetricKeySizeInBits;
    property  OnAsymGenProgress: TGenerateAsymetricKeyPairProgress
                                           read GetAsymGenProgressEvent write SetAsymGenProgressEvent;
    property isUserAborted: boolean              read GetAborted write SetAborted;
  end;


implementation

end.
```

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the LockBox writers suggest to place the source folders in your library path, does not mean you have to. It's handy for tracing into their code, but not required.

Just remove them from that list and add the .dcu directory `d:\LockBox3\packages\Sydney\Delphi\Win32\Release\` to it.

This makes the error go away, and I don't need RTTI in the LockBox sources.

Answer (score 1):

You need to rebuild the dcus with run time information. The simplest way to do this (which also only includes the dcu in this project, not all projects) is to include the source file uTPLb_codecIntf.pas in you project and build the project. You may need to repeat the process for other source files depending on what RTTI you need.

Comment: That is exactly what caused the error in the first place: they *were* getting rebuild (the DCU files ended up in the DCU output folder I had specified in the project options).

Comment: Perhaps a dependent source is causing the error, so one of the files in the uses clause. Does the error occur on a specific line? If so, is there a class type from a different unit on that line? If so, you also need to include that unit in your project. And so on.

Comment: I have `uTPLb_Constants, uTPLb_CryptographicLibrary, uTPLb_BaseNonVisualComponent, uTPLb_Codec` in the Uses clause of two of my units.

Comment: Sorry, I meant in the uses clause of uTPLb_codecIntf.pas. A class in this unit could refer to a class in another unit which has not been rebuilt. The original dcu (without RTTI info) of that unit would still be visible to the project. That unit would also need to be in your projrct so it can be rebuilt.